# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_escape() in C:\wamp\www\MOH\CHWs.php on line 22

Tags: php, curl

I am writing a small program that should invoke HTTP Trigger in frontlineSMS and am getting the above error. My php_curl is enabled and confirmed from the phpInfo().
I have removed semicolons before the php_curl.dll entry in php.ini, and am still getting the above error.

Comment: Psychic powers engage...

Answer (score 0):

`Curl_escape()` is only for php 5.5 and up.

I guess you are using a lower PHP version.
Try upgrading your php :-)